# Determing value of ERC-20 token

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, create2

In developing a new ERC-20 token, can you determine the value of the token? Can you make them worth a different fraction of an ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after developed ERC20 tokens, there are several ways to determine its value.
And there are two main ways to do it.

1. Create a DEX for the token so that the users can buy and sell the token.

While this, the token price will be stable.

2. Presale the token and create the DEX after it.

On presale, you can set the price as you want.

Comment: What is a DEX? Also...can I use a private consortium?

Answer (score 0):

You need a AMM. You need to write a factory contract that will deploy a new token that stores the amountof tokenA and WETH. If you have a 100/100 fraction then your token is worth of one WETH and so on,

Comment: What is AMM? And what is WETH?